# ViewPager и меню. Вызов метода из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть viewPager c двумя фрагментами и меню. Меню прописано в MainActivity.. фрагменты в отдельных классах (Fragment1, Fragment2). При нажатии на пункт меню нужно вызывать метод из Fragment1.
Вроде бы нужно использовать:

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByid(R.id. ???);
fragment1.method();
```

либо

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(???);
fragment1.method();
```

Но я не пойму какое id нужно, где его взять? Либо Tag, как задать?

Comment: Выглядит как плохо продуманная архитектура. Если вам надо из активити достучаться к методу фрагмента - реализуйте через интерфейсы. пример есть в документации activity fragment communication в гугл

Comment: @Sviat Volkov Т.е. в классе фрагмента лучше не размещать код логики?

Comment: Если имеется в виду options menu, то лучше обработать нажатие пункта в самом фрагменте.